# Swift : Core Data accidentally delete extra objects

Tags: swift, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext, nsfetchrequest

I want to delete some specific data on Core Data. I'm deleting objects from tableView, but when I delete the object, some data also deleting after the process. Sometimes It is the last, sometimes It is random data. I don't understand what's going on in my code without my request.

I'm calling `myDeleteObject` in    `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {`

Code :

```
func myDeleteObject(indexPath: NSIndexPath){

    let context:NSManagedObjectContext = ((UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate)).managedObjectContext
    let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Log")
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false;

    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

    do
    {
        let results = try context.executeFetchRequest(request)
        for managedObject in results
        {
            if managedObject.valueForKey("name") as! String == nameArray?.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).valueForKey("name") as! String{
            let managedObjectData:NSManagedObject = managedObject as! NSManagedObject
            context.deleteObject(managedObjectData as NSManagedObject)
            }
        }
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Detele all data in Logs error : \(error) \(error.userInfo)")
    }

}
```

Note : I tried with simulator and everything is fine. But when I try with my iPhone 5S, I'm dealing this problem.

Comment: what do u store in nameArray?

Comment: I'm getting string values in it. I tried with simulators now and nothing wrong with simulator. I don't get it.